# Can't find or re-create Mattermost channel

Tags: mattermost

I was pretty sure we had a channel that I no longer see. When I try to create it, I get "A channel with that URL was previously created."

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Mattermost 3.6 or more recent, you can restore deleted channels by running the following CLI command in the Mattermost `bin` directory:

```
sudo ./platform channel restore team-handle:channel-handle
```

The `team-handle` is the bit of the URL part for the team this channel belongs to, and the `channel-handle` is the handle/URL part that is triggering the error message you report in your question.

See the [Mattermost CLI documentation](https://docs.mattermost.com/administration/command-line-tools.html#platform-channel-restore) for more detailed documentation on how to use it.

Comment: I am not root. I can ask our sysadmin. I have no idea why the channel would have disappeared in the first place.

Comment: @abalter someone probably went and deleted the channel, when that happens it doesn't actually gets deleted, it gets archived, hence, the unique name you used for the channel is still taken by the archived channel, so when you try to create a new one with the same name you get the error that you saw. We solved this by restoring the channel and renaming it by appending `_archived` to the name to free up the name for a new copy of the channel. Then archiving the renamed version and creating the new channel.

Comment: Please note, that this command is an Enterprise Feature in Mattermost (Error: Feature requires an enterprise license) and not executable in the Community Edition.

Comment: @pixelbrackets as of 4.3 (due to be released on 16th October) this will no longer be an enterprise feature, and will be available in the open source Team Edition as well.